# How to have a correct user experience based on different user roles ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization

I wanted to implement different user functionality based on their role in ASP.NET Web API, currently I have a `ProductController` which is responsible for all the operations with the product. What I want to do is to have single product controller and to separate it with different functionality like so:

- Admin can delete and update any user and product
- User can delete and update only their product
- Super user can get products hidden information

My question is: how can I use only the product and user controllers to perform such operations? I really want to use claims, but I heard I can't have them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could very easily have that applied to your ASP.NET Web API controllers—the role-based functionality using claims-based authorization. In a scenario where you would have roles (Admin, User, Super User) with certain permissions, you would follow these steps:

**Configure Role-Based Authorization**

- Define Roles: Ensure that your user entity or authentication process
  defines roles (Admin, User, Super User).
- Assign Roles to Users: When a user is created or updated, assign the
  appropriate role to them.
- Include role claims: The role, in this case, should be one of the
  claims in the process of verifying authenticity. This is done, in
  most cases, when generating tokens if you are using JWT tokens.

**Apply Authorization in Controllers**

`ProductController`: Secure the controller itself and its actions with
the `[Authorize]` attribute, specifying roles using the same
attribute.

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User, User")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        // Code to get products
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        // Code to delete product
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(int id, Product product)
    {
        // Code to update product, ensure a User can only update their product
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Super User")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetHiddenInfo(int productId)
    {
        // Code to get hidden information
    }
}
```

**User-Specific Logic**

- The logic of finding out whether the user is the owner of the product
  will be put into action for the operations in which a User can only
  modify his products.

```cs
[HttpPut]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProduct(int id, Product product)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var existingProduct = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

    if (existingProduct == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (existingProduct.OwnerId != userId && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    // Update product logic here
}
```

**Configure Authentication Middleware**

- Ensure that your authentication middleware is configured to support
  roles. If you use JWT tokens, parse the token and set the principal
  with the roles claim.

**A few reference links helping detail understanding and guidance towards the role-based authorization using ASP.NET Web API are as follows:**

- Understanding Role-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Web API:
  Microsoft's guide on authorization in ASP.NET Web API offers a
  comprehensive overview: [Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).
- Implementing Claims-Based Authentication: This article provides insight into the way claims-based authentication is implemented, which is invaluable to role-based authorization: [Claims-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#roles).
- Role-Based Authorization: If you want to know more about role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core, take a look at "[Role-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0)" Though this resource was written for ASP.NET Core, the majority of information applies to one of its modules—ASP.NET Web API.
- JWT Token Authentication: If you're using JWT tokens, understanding how to work with them in ASP.NET is crucial: [JWT Validation and Authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).
- Securing Web API: This guide offers a comprehensive look at securing an ASP.NET Web API: [Securing ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/).
- Custom Authorization Filter in Web API: For scenarios where you need custom authorization logic: [Custom Authorization in Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters).

Comment: Thank you, your sources helped me figure out how to add authorization for my application. In my case I had to add a single custom policy and pass userId into Claims. Works like a charm!

Comment: It is simpler than that. I am happy that the response and the sources worked. Thank you for your response.